# What is the difference between content aware tool, patch, and spot healing?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing

SO I am a beginner in photoshop. My question is-

What is the difference between content aware tool, patch, and spot healing?

All of them do the same thing, then why are there 3 different tools for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Content Aware** = You delete something and the program automatically tries to fill the place with some stuff that's taken from the environmet. The purpose is to make all look out continuous (=nothing removed). This works if the environment of the deletion contains only simple regular geometry that can  be extended over the deletion believably

**Patch** = You delete something and you can show, where the replacement is taken from; hover the mouse around and click when a good replacement seems to have been pointed. Bonus: Automatic color matching for the best continuity.

**Spot healing**: A piece of differently colored crap is detected automatically under the mouse cursor and replaced by the environment color. The size of the brush must be larger than the piece of the crap for complete fix

*Addendum:*
Often the automatic color matching is a bad thing. Just in the neighbourhood of a differently colored area you easily lose the strict border between the different colors. You will soon learn to use the simple cloning as your favorite patching tool.

Comment: oh, but what do you mean by "Bonus: Automatic color matching for the best continuity." ?

Comment: The color of the patch is adjusted to fit seamlessly. If you take something from elsewhere for patching, it is rare to have both the form and the color ok at the same time. Autoadjusting the color is a great help.

Comment: oh, yeah so you can manually adjust colors!

Comment: The automatic color matching is purposed to make manual adjustments unnecessary. In a hurry to get a photo fixed one really has something else to do than match the color of a little patch.

Comment: oh, so the advantage is that it matches colors too!

Comment: so content aware tool is just a larger version of spot healing right?